# How to design for devices between hdpi and xhdpi

Tags: android, android-layout, metrics, display, hdpi

I'm using these `res drawable` folders in my application every thing is fine, until recently I installed my app in `Sony C3` device its dpi is ~267 but screen size is 5.5" which makes it `hdpi` device with large screen. It is taking the dimensions from `hdpi` and a huge space is left in the screen..! making text small.

how to design for this devices is there any other `drawable` folder for `~280dp` or I have to create my own? please tell me how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-sw<N>dp` folders. (e.g. `drawable-sw240dp`)

This should help to specify a matching layout.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: my problem is my sony c3 is 5.5" but falls under hdpi category and my Lenovo is 5" device comes under xhdpi. I designed my hdpi devices for 4.7" screens so hdpi is working correctly for small devices but becoming problem when device is BIG..

Comment: the -sw notation replaces the concept of hdpi as a fixed point. Just don't use hdpi. Instead use several folders with sw.